# Writing over dotted lines using php/html?

Tags: html

I've a html form like this.

[image]

Over the dots I'm going to pull data from my mysql db using php, I'm not finding the trick how can I write over those dotted lines, writing over dotted lines is the requirement.

a sample field using jsfiddle I've 50+ fields where I need to pull data from php and write over dotted lines like firstname, dob etc.

js fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/mCHpG/

```
<TABLE cellpadding=0 cellspacing=0 class="t0">
<TR>
    <TD class="tr1 td2"><P class="p7 ft1">1.</P></TD>
    <TD class="tr1 td3"><P class="p8 ft1">Full name </P></TD>
    <TD class="tr1 td1"><P class="p6 ft1">………………………………………………</P></TD>
</TR>
</table>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**CSS:**

```
.datatext{
 border-bottom:1px dotted;   
 width : 250px;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<TABLE cellpadding=0 cellspacing=0 class="t0">
<TR>
    <TD class="tr1 td2"><P class="p7 ft1">1.</P></TD>
    <TD class="tr1 td3"><P class="p8 ft1">Full name </P></TD>
    <TD class="tr1 td1"><P class="p6 ft1 datatext"> John Doe</P></TD>
</TR>
</table>
```

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/tsspinal/yN2ZU/

Answer (score 5):

```
<TABLE cellpadding=0 cellspacing=0 class="t0">
<TR>
    <TD class="tr1 td2"><P class="p7 ft1">1.</P></TD>
    <TD class="tr1 td3"><P class="p8 ft1" style="border-bottom: 1px dotted #000; display: block; width: 200px;">Full name </P></TD>
</TR>
</table>
```

You could do something like this

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6CFXy/)